# Find min value by attribute, return as list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a class similar to this:

```
public class Product{
    public Integer category;
    public Integer price;    

    // getters and setters omitted
}
```

With a list of products with different categories and prices I want to return a list containing the cheapest product for each category. I have found a way to get this as a map with the category as a key, but I'd like to just have a list. What is a concise and readable way to do that?

This is what I have so far that gives me a map:

```
Map<String, Product> cheapestProducts = products.stream()
   .collect(
       groupingBy(                                                      
           Product::getCategory,
               collectingAndThen(minBy(comparing(Product::getPrice)), p -> p.get())
       )
   );
```

Comment: I don't understand. Your code returns a `Map<Integer, Product>`, as expected? Why are you trying to store that in a `Map<String,List<Product>>`? When you have the `Map` you can call `values()`.

Comment: what is the `products`?

Comment: You can simply invoke `.values()` on the `Map` to get a `Collection<Product>`. If it must be a `List`, you pass that collection to the `ArrayList(Collection)` constructor. If you need that all within a `Collector` you can use `collectingAndThen`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) method and then call map.values() :

```
Collection<Product> cheapestProducts = products
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(t -> t.category, u -> u,
                    (a, b) -> a.price > b.price ? b : a))
            .values();
```

Also see Holger's comment above, if you really want a list.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your method is OK. The problem is with readability, and the solution is in my opinion to extract methods to make it reuseable, if needed. Java 8 streams are fluent and so on, but there is often the temptation to make streams which are 20 lines long, which harms readability. So by extracting the method `getMinBy()` (maybe there is a better name for it), which encapsulates the `minBy`, and `Optional::get`, it gets more readable in my opinion. Of course, the method itself is not that concise, but is reusable.

```
    Map<Integer, Product> cheapestProducts = products.stream()
            .collect(
                    groupingBy(
                            Product::getCategory,
                            getMinBy(Product::getPrice)
                    ));


    private static <T,C extends Comparable<? super C>> Collector<T, ?, T> getMinBy(Function<T, C> comparatorFunction) {
        return collectingAndThen(minBy(comparing(comparatorFunction)), Optional::get);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get values from a Map to a list you can do something like this...

```
List<Value> list = new ArrayList<Value>(map.values());
```